# Load Runner - Capture Initial Page Load Time - Ignore Call Back Requests

Tags: httpresponse, loadrunner, page-load-time, response-time

We have a requirement to capture initial page load/paint time while callback requests are loading data on the page. We are using Load Runner performance testing. The average response times for a transaction are 9-10 seconds. However, we are more interested on how quickly the page paints vs the data in each web part is loaded (ignoring JavaScript call back requests). Is there any setting/way to capture such data in Load Runner?

If Load Runner cannot capture/distinguish the data as needed above, is there any other tool perhaps we can use with a browser by executing it manually while we are load test is going on?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> ...how quickly the page paints...

This is a GUI level event, so you will need a virtual user type which samples at the GUI to answer this issue.  If you combine a GUI Virtual User (QTP-based) with a protocol level virtual user (HTTP) for a common named event (Login vs Login_GUI) then you will be able to measure the time inside of the browser.

GUI Virtual Uses have been part of the definition for LoadRunner since version 1.0.   They began as XRunner defined, moved to WinRunner defined and now are defined by QuickTest Professional.